# C# call for 'int foo(QByteArray &memDump)' does not copy into dump into variable

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, overwrite

I'm accessing an activeXserver in a C# programm. One function is defined as
`int foo(QByteArray &memDump)`, which puts its own data onto `memDump`. If the size of the byte array is wrong or the write to `memDump` does not work, I get return values != 0. So I think this must be correct.

I create the byte array with:

```
byte[] dump = new byte[size];
int rtn = foo(dump);
```

Am I doing something essentially wrong here? 
With the address operator in the variable list of `foo`, the function is supposed to work directly on `memDump` and not with a copy of it - but it does not manipulate the data.

Comment: is this C++ Qt or C#?

Comment: I am using C# and the programm that is controlled via activeXserver is written in C++ and QT. Not sure if the type `QByteArray`makes some problems...